# Can someone explain the train function in cifar10_train.py from cifar10 tutorials in tensorflow

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow

I am following cifar10 tutorials from https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/tutorials/image/cifar10.
In this project, there are 6 classes. After searching the internet I understood cifar10.py and cifar10_input.py classes. But I can't understand train function in cifar10_train.py. Here is the train function in cifar10_train.py class.

```
def train():
with tf.Graph().as_default():
    global_step = tf.contrib.framework.get_or_create_global_step()

    # get images and labels for cifar 10
    # Force input pipeline to CPU:0 to avoid operations sometime ending on
    # GPU and resulting in a slow down

    with tf.device('/cpu:0'):
        images, labels = cifar10.distorted_inputs()

    logits = cifar10.inference(images)

    loss = cifar10.loss(logits, labels)

    train_op = cifar10.train(loss, global_step)

    class _LoggerHook(tf.train.SessionRunHook):

        def begin(self):
            self._step = -1
            self._start_time = time.time()

        def before_run(self, run_context):
            self._step += 1
            return tf.train.SessionRunArgs(loss)

        def after_run(self, run_context, run_values):
            if self._step % FLAGS.log_frequency == 0:
                current_time = time.time()
                duration = current_time - self._start_time
                self._start_time = current_time

                loss_value = run_values.results
                examples_per_sec = FLAGS.log_frequency * FLAGS.batch_size / duration
                sec_per_batch = float(duration / FLAGS.log_frequency)

                format_str = ('%s: step %d, loss = %.2f (%.1f examples/sec; %.3f '
                              'sec/batch)')
                print(format_str % (datetime.now(), self._step, loss_value,
                                    examples_per_sec, sec_per_batch))

    with tf.train.MonitoredTrainingSession(
            checkpoint_dir=FLAGS.train_dir,
            hooks=[tf.train.StopAtStepHook(last_step=FLAGS.max_steps),
                   tf.train.NanTensorHook(loss),
                   _LoggerHook()],
            config=tf.ConfigProto(
                log_device_placement=FLAGS.log_device_placement)) as mon_sess:
        while not mon_sess.should_stop():
            mon_sess.run(train_op)
```

Can someone please explain what is happening in _LoggerHook class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It uses `MonitoredSession` and `SessionRunHook` for logging the loss when training.

`_LoggerHook` is an implementation of `SessionRunHook` that runs in an order described below:

```
  call hooks.begin()
  sess = tf.Session()
  call hooks.after_create_session()
  while not stop is requested:
    call hooks.before_run()
    try:
      results = sess.run(merged_fetches, feed_dict=merged_feeds)
    except (errors.OutOfRangeError, StopIteration):
      break
    call hooks.after_run()
  call hooks.end()
  sess.close()
```

It's from [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.3/tensorflow/python/training/session_run_hook.py#L69).

It collects `loss` data before the `session.run` then outputs `loss` with a predefined format.

A tutorial: https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/layers

Hope this hopes.